setsockopt Timeout Not working Properly In Raspberry Pi
I am working with Raspberry Pi 4 with bookworm 64bit OS for connecting devices with TCP/IP.
I need some delay for socket timeout if no response from my server. The Raspberry Pi acts as a client. I am using the following C program code for the socket. In that, for a timeout I use setsockopt(), but it doesn't create the expected time delay. After some fraction of seconds, it is getting a timeout. I want a minimum 2 seconds delay.
int sockfd,Soccon,DataIn;
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct timeval tv;
char GpmsData[4000],Gpms[20];

sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.148");
server.sin_family=AF_INET;
server.sin_port=htons(30000);
tv.tv_sec= 5; // 5 seconds delay
tv.tv_usec=0;
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,(const char *)&tv, sizeof(tv));
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDTIMEO,(const char *)&tv, sizeof(tv));
Soccon=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server)) ;
Gpms[0]=0x01;
Gpms[1]=0x03;
Gpms[2]=0x02;
Gpms[3]=0x00;
Gpms[4]=0x03;
Gpms[5]=0x00;
Gpms[6]=0x05;
if(send(sockfd,Gpms,7,0)<0)
  {
   printf("Data Sending Problem\n");
  }
else
  {
   printf("Data Sended\n");
   DataIn=read(sockfd,GpmsData,3800);
   if(DataIn<0)
      {
       printf("Data Not Received\n");
      }
  }

If the server is not responding, it doesn't wait for 5 seconds. After some milliseconds, it is timing out immediately.
Is there any issue with the OS, or something in my code? Please guide me to resolve the issue.

The default is to never timeout. What happens if you omit the calls to setsockopt? If the client still doesn't receive a response from the server, the reason is not any timeout, because none was set.

How do you know it is timing out quicker? There is nothing in the code you showed that checks for that condition. Is read() returning sooner than 5 seconds? What is the actual return value? Are you seeing the Data Not Received error and assuming it is related to a timeout problem? What is the actual error reported by errno?  Use perror() instead of printf()

If i am omitting setsockopt it is keep on waiting for the response i need to timeout certain period if data not received

using the printf statement i am able to know the timeout is quicker than expected read() sooner than 5 seconds actually i am arranged simulation from my office to check the data availability.
